# Convert (integer,precision) pair to a float in bash/bc

Tags: bash, shell, bc

I have two numbers, $value and $precision. I need to make a "floating-point" representation of these numbers (though of course the output will actually be a string, since this is bash).

$precision tells me how many decimal points the number should have.

Example:

```
  $value=123, $precision=2
```

This should give the output "1.23".

How can I do this elegantly from Bash? I am looking at the "bc" man page but I'm not really seeing any way there. I assume the simplest way is to treat my input value as a string and insert the char '.' in the right position somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `bc`:

```
bc <<EOF
scale = $precision
$value / (10 ^ $precision)
EOF
```

In `sed`:

```
sed -e "s/[0-9]\{$precision\}$/.&/" <<< "$value"
```

Comment: I'll go with the sed solution, at least I can read and understand that.

The bc expression gives me the following error, on Solaris 10:

    syntax error on line 1, teletype

Comment: @Jolta: sorry, I was having a brain freeze while testing, and I removed the '=' from the 'scale' line as a passing attempted fix (before I realized I'd not set the bash variables, if you need to know).  And I didn't refix it before hitting submit.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so I found some string manipulation help for Bash ... This does the trick, but it is hardly pretty. Posting it here for posterity.

```
lastIndex=$((${#value}-1))
dotIndex=$((${#value}-$precision))
decvalue=${value:0:$dotIndex}.${value:$dotIndex:$lastIndex}
```

Comment: You really don't need the back-ticks or the echo; you can use just: `decvalue="${value:0:$precision}.${value:$last}"` where the double quotes are optional too.  Also, doesn't this give `12.3` rather than `1.23`?

Comment: Thanks! My expression was faulty and actually gave me 1.3... But now it gives me 12.3 as you say. Any suggestions to turn that around?

Comment: OK, I think this does the trick. But it's ugly!
On the other hand, my whole script runs in ca 0.190s using the sed solution, and ca 0.180s using this ugly one! ;-)

Comment: Well, I hope you can make good use of the extra 1/100th of a second each time you use this script :)  Your amended version looks like what I was going to assemble.  I note that `bash` could benefit from learning from Perl, that negative offsets meaning 'from the end of the string' can be handy (it would save you some of those calculations).

Comment: Well, if I run the script n times a minute... It'd still be O(n). Never mind.